# Django: Using a nested TextChoice class values in a Meta class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I used to declare TextChoices classes inside the model class like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    class OrderStatusChoices(models.TextChoices):
        NEW = 'NEW'
        CLOSED = 'CLOSED'
        CANCELLED = 'CANCELLED'
        
    status = models.CharField(choices=OrderStatusChoices.choices, max_length=9)
```

In this case, I was instantiating the class as:

```
from models import Order

order = Order(status=Order.OrderStatusChoices.NEW)
```

Now I need to use the TextChoices values in the Meta class to check the database constraint:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    class OrderStatusChoices(models.TextChoices):
        NEW = 'NEW'
        CLOSED = 'CLOSED'
        CANCELLED = 'CANCELLED'

    status = models.CharField(choices=OrderStatusChoices.choices, max_length=9)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_status_valid',
                check=models.Q(status__in=OrderStatusChoices.values)
            )
        ]
```

However, if the status class is nested within the order class, the textchoice cannot be referenced (Unresolved reference 'OrderStatusChoices' ).
This can be solved by taking the status class out of the order class:

```
class OrderStatusChoices(models.TextChoices):
    NEW = 'NEW'
    CLOSED = 'CLOSED'
    CANCELLED = 'CANCELLED'


class Order(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(choices=OrderStatusChoices.choices, max_length=9)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_status_valid',
                check=models.Q(status__in=OrderStatusChoices.values)
            )
        ]
```

But this does not make it very convenient to import (for me, maybe I'm wrong and this is normal) the order model without status textchoice and in order to create an instance of the order class, you need to import both the order model and the status textchoice:

```
from models import Order, OrderStatusChoices

order = Order(status=OrderStatusChoices.NEW)
```

In case there are few models and they have few textchoices, you can still remember this and perform such an import, but I think if the project becomes large, it will be quite inconvenient.In case there are few models and they have few textchoices, you can still remember this and perform such an import, but I think if the project becomes large, it will be quite inconvenient.

Tell me, are there any other options for using textchoice values in the Meta class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a possible workaround you can assign the outer class to an `Order`'s attribute with the same name explicitly, therefore you will be able to access it  in both ways.

```
class OrderStatusChoices(models.TextChoices):
    ...


class Order(models.Model):
    OrderStatusChoices = OrderStatusChoices
    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_status_valid',
                check=models.Q(status__in=OrderStatusChoices.values)
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Yep, I also made an attribute inside the class.  There doesn't seem to be a more elegant way.  Thank you!